# Does user authentification prevent concurrency issues?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, concurrency

I am using LINQ to SQL in order to read/write a database on a server. Right now only the creator of an db-entry can change the according information.

Is it guaranteed that thereby no concurrency issues should appear? I mean it is not possible that one entry is changed simultaniously form two different locations. Or are there also read-concurrent problems that could appear?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would authentication of different users have anything to do with concurrency issues?

Comment: Two people (or simply browsers) could authenticate using the same username/password and change the data concurrently.

Comment: Unanswereable due to lack of details. Thread safety requires understanding the **whole system**. You gave us almost nothing to look at. Vote to close.

Comment: Dont worry I got my awnser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No; that won't help at all.

A single user can still send multiple concurrent requests from different tabs or browsers or machines.

Answer (score 0):

Excluding the obvious unlikely case of a "malicious" user using mutiple windows I wonder if strange scenarios could happen:

- The user sends its first request which is executed on a thread by the web server but for whatever reason this thread is preempted.
- Then later the same user emits another request that is in conflict with the first one, but this request is executed on a thread which is not preempted and directly writes a new value to the DB.
- The first thread is then awakened and ends its works writing the old value

So when you have any doubt put some safeguards because we're never too careful, especially when programming ;)

Comment: By safeguard, do you mean something like "Context.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode.ContinueOnConflict);" ?

Comment: I've never used it so I can't say if this would help for every scenario.

Comment: @Serious the "strange scenario" you came up with is in effect the same thing as the "malicious user" (barring user intent, of course). Both are just multiple requests being sent concurrently; it doesn't have anything to do with having multiple windows open, etc.

Comment: It's not exactly the same thing: in my scenario there is no multiple requests being "sent" but multiple operations being "executed" out-of-order. I wanted to present a more subtle scenario than "the user uses multiple screens" scenario because even if all your users are "safe" your technical stack (network + web server + web framework + platform + OS) may not be.

Answer (score 0):

In an ideal world yes. But there are several things to consider.

Can the same user submit changes from multiple locations?

If the TCP/IP connection is broken and reestablished will overlapping/out of order requests be an issue?

Is there any possiblity of needing moderator or admin access to user data?